# How can I fetch two consecutive array objects simultaneously with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say we have an array in our controller as follows:

```
$scope.elements = [
  {
    title: title-1,
    desc: description-1
  },
  {
    title: title-2,
    desc: description-2
  },
  {
    title: title-3,
    desc: description-3
  },
  {
    title: title-4,
    desc: description-4
  }
]
```

I wish to loop through the array so I can place the elements as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[0].title }}
    {{ elements[0].desc }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[1].title }}
    {{ elements[1].desc }}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[2].title }}
    {{ elements[2].desc }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[3].title }}
    {{ elements[3].desc }}
  </div>
</div>
```

...and so on.

This could be achieved if we could fetch two consecutive elements simultaneously via an `ng-repeat` and pass it to the directive. Can this be done? Also if so, how would the fetched array objects be handled inside the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the $index property to do this. The hiding with `ng-if` is a little inefficient, if this is a huge repeat, you might want a more elegant solution.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-if="$index <=  elements.length /2">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[$index*2].title }}
    {{ elements[$index*2].desc }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="elements[$index*2 + 1]"> //ng-if for if you want to remove last element if odd array.
    {{ elements[$index*2 + 1].title }}
    {{ elements[$index*2 + 1].desc }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would it do if the array length is odd? In that case, won't it create an empty second `.col-sm-6`?

Comment: Yes. I added an edit if that's not desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. This looks like a fine piece of code. I'd run though this code to adapt it to my problem first thing in the morning tomorrow, and if it works as expected, you get to keep your fortune cookie. =)

Comment: Glad I could help! Just keep in mind that it does create a little extra overhead in extra watchers for the `ng-if`s. Massaging the data first is the cleanest solution. This is fine for relatively small repeats (less than 500?)

Comment: Hey Dylan, Thanks for the answer. Works like a charm. Can you tell me how I could put this code in a directive say `<my-dir info="element"></my-dir>` where `element in elements` loops in the container of the directive? I tried putting the above code inside a directive but it didn't work.

Comment: It should work fine. Maybe the collection is "info" and thus "element in info" in your directive. If not, just make a new SO question with your current directive structure.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be as simple as creating another array to iterate over

```
$scope.TemplateArray = [
[0,1],
[2,3],
etc...
]
```

Then use this for your ng-repeat
array in TemplateArray

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[array[0]].title }}
    {{ elements[array[0]].desc }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ elements[array[1]].title }}
    {{ elements[array[1]].desc }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of this approach, but would it be sensible to change the organization of your dataset for the sake of formatting it on the webpage?

Comment: You wouldn't change it from the API, you'd massage it on the client after you get the data. Ideally a data API is agnostic of the view.

Comment: You are both correct, if you have access to the API, and it makes sense to transform the data.  This is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is going to be to pre-process your array into groups of however many columns you have and then ng-repeat over that array. So pre-process your elements into something that looks like:

```
$scope.processedElements = [
   [{title:'1',desc:'1d'},{title:'2',desc:'2d'},{title:'3',desc:'3d'},{title:'4',desc:'4d'}],
   [{title:'5',desc:'5d},.......      ]

];
```

and then

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in processedElements">
      {{item[0].title}} {{item[1].title}}       // etc. etc

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your problem to a limit

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('example', function($scope) {
  $scope.limit = 2;
  $scope.elements = [];
  $scope.$watch('limit', function() {
    $scope.elements = elements;
  });
  elements = [{
    title: 'title-1',
    desc: 'description-1'
  }, {
    title: 'title-2',
    desc: 'description-2'
  }, {
    title: ' title-3',
    desc: 'description-3'
  }, {
    title: 'title-4',
    desc: 'description-4'
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="example">
    <input type="number" ng-model="limit">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="el in elements" ng-if="$index < limit">
        {{el.title}} {{el.desc}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>seperator</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="el in elements" ng-if="$index >= limit">
        {{el.title}} {{el.desc}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't have only four objects in my array. The sample array in the question is just for example. I wish to figure out a one-size-fits-all solution for this. The above solution would put array items indexed 0 and 1 inside to first `.row` element, and put all the remaining array items irrespective of their index into the second `.row` element.

Comment: you can always use some limiting variable instead of constants